# How to install Corrosion on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, rust

The [Corrosion website](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/corrosion-develop-rust-applications-eclipse-ide) says that I just need to drag the install button to an open Eclipse workspace. When I do that, all it does is open Eclipse Marketplace (yes, that is installed); it doesn't install anything, and marketplace doesn't appear to contain Corrosion (and the only thing I can find for Rust is RustDT, no longer supported). What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe your Eclipse is too old. Which Eclipse version do you have? If it is older than Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11), please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: That could be it; I'm at Eclipse 4.7. But I can't work out how to upgrade - where is the repository? I've got http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen in my list of available software sites, but it's showing me no upgrades available (as you can tell, I'm not a regular Eclipse user!)

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ add the update site [`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest) and do _Help > Check for Updates_.

Comment: Thanks - my problem was finding the right update site.